# Euler-Maclaurin Formula Definition Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, bernoulli-numbers, euler-maclaurin

I am confused about these $2$ definitions of the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

I read the following [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cms_upload/mathmag61-65-spivey15625.pdf):

> The full Euler-Maclaurin formula with no remainder term (for infinitely differentiable $f$ ) is given in Concrete Mathematics [2, p. 471]:
>
> $\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}{f(j)}=\int_{0}^{m}{f(x)dx}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{B_k}{k!}\left(f^{(k-1)}(m)-f^{(k-1)}(0)\right)}$.

But the wikipedia article found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) says this:

> Explicitly, for $p$ a positive integer and a function $f(x)$ that is $p$ times continuously differentiable in the interval $[m,n]$, we have
>
> $S-I=\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\frac{B_k}{k!}\left(f^{(k-1)}(n)-f^{(k-1)}(m)\right)}+R_p$

My question is, if a function is infinitely differentiable over a given interval, how can the wikipedia definition hold since infinity is not an integer?

I could not find a reference that gives the definition the way Wikipedia does. Can anyone explain the discrepancy between the two definitions? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If a function is infinitely differentiable, then it is $p$ times differentiable for every positive integer $p$.  Also, if you look at the paper more closely, you'll see that it's the formula with remainder that is used to prove the theorems about sums of integer powers.

Comment: @saulspatz, if a function is infinitely differentiable though, what value would I plug in for the upper bound, $p$, since the wikipedia formula gives $p$ explicitly as an integer? Also, is a function $f(x)=x^3$ is $4$ times differentiable or infinitely times differentiable in the case of this formula?

Comment: If it's infinitely differentiable you can use any $p$ you like.   Just as in Taylor's formula, you get different estimates using different numbers of terms.  The difference is, however, that the Euler-MacLaurin formula is not necessarily convergent, and then one tries to pick the value of $p$ that will give the smallest (or at least an acceptably small) error.  

$f(x)=x^3$ is infinitely differentiable, and *a fortiori* it's also $4$ times differentiable.

Comment: @saulspatz, Thank you, that clears it up for me, I did not realize that $p$ is arbitrary depending on how much error is acceptable.